# How do you host a Ruby on Rails application on a home server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

As the title suggests, how can I host a Ruby on Rails application on a home server. I want to be able to develop on linux and then deploy on a server running linux. I know there's PaaS out there that help with deployment and host but for a specific job I need to be able to do it on a computer that will act as a server.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a RoR project on your local computer just for development? If so this is not the place to start. There are TONS of articles/videos/documentation to do that. SO is for specific code questions, not tutorials.

Comment: I'm asking to run a RoR project on a local computer for production. I want to be able to do development on my computer but push to production on my local server. I just don't know if that's possible because a lot of guides that I've read so far require subscriptions to hosting services.

Comment: I wrote a series of posts here about setting up a ruby Sinatra app on a raspberry pi http://rawsyntax.com/blog/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi/

Comment: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 https://gist.github.com/he9lin/1255821 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu/ I think you get the point  literally googled "Setup a rails production server"

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing 'run a RoR project on a local computer for production' is a little strange.

If you just want to do development on your PC and have somewhere that will host your production app for free and you can push to from your PC (i.e. the way most development works) you want [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5).

If you literally want to use your computer as the server for a production app you can use something like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which creates a tunnel from the web to your localhost. However you would definitely not want to run most applications like this because if you ever shut down or even closed your computer the site would stop working. Additionally I would guess there's security concerns with using your computer as a server for a publicly accessible URL for any extended period, though I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Sorry I guess the way I phrased it wasn't correct. I have a server computer that just needs to be configured so I can be able to do development and deploy to that server. I should've been more specific. I know there's such thing as heroku and digitalocean that basically take care of server side configuration for you but had trouble finding information that didn't rely on paying a hosting company, my bad..